# How do I replace a character in the string with another charater in fortran

Tags: string, fortran

I have a string "f://asd/aww/asdf.txt" and I need to change it to "f:\asd\aww\asdf.txt". is it feasible?

Comment: Did you try any code? How are your variables declared? I simple loop with one if statement should suffice. Do you really need `f://` with two slashes and `f:\` with one slash? Note that the forward slash usually works in Windows as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this in the past, so here is a recursive way of replacing parts of  an input `string` that match the pattern of arbitrary length given by `search` input argument with a substitute string of also arbitrary size given by the input argument `substitute`.

```
module String_mod

    implicit none
    public

!***********************************************************************************************************************************
!***********************************************************************************************************************************

contains

!***********************************************************************************************************************************
!***********************************************************************************************************************************

    pure recursive function replaceStr(string,search,substitute) result(modifiedString)
        implicit none
        character(len=*), intent(in)  :: string, search, substitute
        character(len=:), allocatable :: modifiedString
        integer                       :: i, stringLen, searchLen
        stringLen = len(string)
        searchLen = len(search)
        if (stringLen==0 .or. searchLen==0) then
            modifiedString = ""
            return
        elseif (stringLen<searchLen) then
            modifiedString = string
            return
        end if
        i = 1
        do
            if (string(i:i+searchLen-1)==search) then
                modifiedString = string(1:i-1) // substitute // replaceStr(string(i+searchLen:stringLen),search,substitute)
                exit
            end if
            if (i+searchLen>stringLen) then
                modifiedString = string
                exit
            end if
            i = i + 1
            cycle
        end do
    end function replaceStr

!***********************************************************************************************************************************
!***********************************************************************************************************************************

end module String_mod

program testReplaceStr

use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: output_unit
use String_mod
implicit none

write( output_unit, "(*(g0,:,' '))" ) replaceStr( string = "f://asd/aww/asdf.txt" &
                                                , search = "/" &
                                                , substitute = "\" &
                                                )

end program testReplaceStr
```

```sh
D:\>ifort /debug:full /Zi /CB /Od /Qinit:snan /warn:all /gen-interfaces /traceback /check:all /check:bounds /fpe-all:0 /Qdiag-error-limit:10 /Qtrapuv main.f90 -o main.exe
Intel(R) Visual Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 19.0.4.245 Build 20190417
Copyright (C) 1985-2019 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.22.27905.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

-out:main.exe
-debug
-pdb:main.pdb
-subsystem:console
-incremental:no
main.obj
```

```sh
D:\>main.exe
f:\\asd\aww\asdf.txt
```

Keep in mind that this approach is likely not the best for performance considerations as it involves multiple recursive memory allocations for the final string construction, depending on how many times the `search` pattern appears in the input `string`.

Comment: The performance is better than expected even for long strings.