# Fortran OPEN function receives the wrong file name

Tags: fortran

Edit: see answer for explanation. There is not enough information in this question to solve.

I have a very simple issue that I cannot seem to crack. I am opening a file in fortran 90 that is in a directory. Here is the code:

```
write(*,'(A,A)') "[I] found ", trim(fullname)
open(unit=handleId, file=trim(fullname),status='unknown')
```

This gives the output:

```
[I] found restartIn2D/restart_time.dat
At line 106 of file navier_stokes/RestartDirAsIC.F90 (unit = 983) ! the open(...) line
Fortran runtime error: Cannot open file 'restartIn2D': Is a directory
```

I must be missing something, but it appears that `trim(fullname)` fives two different things when invoked on the two lines I provided. I also checked the iostat, which returns a value of 21, apparently corresponding to:

```
FOR$IOS_DUPFILSPE. Multiple attempts were made to specify file attributes without an 
intervening close operation. A DEFINE FILE statement was followed by another DEFINE FILE 
statement or an OPEN statement.
```

Which is inconsistent with the run-time error message. I should note that I have checked that unit 983 is available and it is. What is happening here?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] and the complete output.

Comment: Does the directory exist and do you have permission to write into that directory?

Comment: Unseen factors were affecting this situation. I will post an answer explaining.

Answer (score 2):

Unsurprisingly, there was an issue somewhere else in my code. My vairable `fullname` was a combination of other variables, namely given as

```
write(fullname, "(A,A,A)") trim(directoryName), "/", trim(filename)
```

The variable `directoryName` was explicitly copied from a character array as such:

```
do ns=1,120
    directoryName(ns:ns)=read2DICFromDirectory(ns)
end do
```

The variable `read2DICFromDirectory` has a C binding:

```
character(kind=C_CHAR), bind(C,name="read2DICFromDirectory_ "), dimension(120) :: read2DICFromDirectory
```

And it was being initialized explicitly with null terminators:

```
char read2DICFromDirectory_[120];
for (int k = 0; k < 120; k++) read2DICFromDirectory_[k] = 0;
```

Clearly, the `trim` function was not removing these null characters from `directoryName`. When printed to the terminal, nothing showed up, but the `open` function was being affected by the null terminators (probably written in C), thereby only trying to open the directory.

Comment: I love Fortran, but I hate Fortran strings. Just ranting.

Comment: TRIM removes trailing blanks.  It isn't supposed to remove any other character, which means it won't remove C null characters.  If you mix Fortran and C, you have to attend to the differences between the languages.

Comment: You can likely use this `replaceStr()` function to replace null characters ( `achar(0)` ) with nothing (`""`) in your full file name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938347/how-do-i-replace-a-character-in-the-string-with-another-charater-in-fortran/58980957#58980957